# Unable to place an Object of java class in another class

Tags: java

i have two java classes in a package. I want to create one class's object into another but it gives an error message ERROR: cannot find symbol.

```
package pckg;
public class aa{
   private String name;
   public aa(){} //Constructor of aa class
   public void setName(String name){this.name=name;}
   public String getName(){return name;}
}

package pckg;
public class bb{
   aa obj = new aa(); //This line gives error message

   public bb(){} //Constructor of bb class

}
```

both classes are in a same folder pckg.

ERROR Message:

```
D:\Java\mypack>cd..

D:\Java>cd pckg

D:\Java\pckg>set path=d:\java\jdk1.5\bin

D:\Java\pckg>javac aa.java

D:\Java\pckg>javac bb.java
bb.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class aa
location: class pckg.bb
aa obj = new aa(); //This line gives error message
^
bb.java:3: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class aa 
location: class pckg.bb
aa obj = new aa(); //This line gives error message
            ^
2 errors
```

Comment: Could you post the printstacktrace? At a glance your code seems ok. Those classes, are in separate java files right?

Comment: yes there are two different files in one package. aa.java and bb.java

Comment: Could you paste the error trace on your IDE? Or you compile and run it in the terminal?

Comment: @djakapm i've edited my post. Please check the error

Comment: you need to set the class path as the current directory

Comment: @djakapm how to set the class path? This is what i do not know how to?

Comment: i tried this `D:\java\pckg>set classpath=%classpath%;.` but it did not work

Comment: Please see the 'Answers' section below...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
D:\Java\ > javac -classpath . pckg\aa.java
D:\Java\ > javac -classpath . pckg\bb.java
```

If you don't specify a classpath, javac doesn't know where to find the already compiled classes.

Also, classes should start with an upper-case letter in Java. And I would avoid using the same directory for the source files and class files. You'd better put your sources inside d:\Java\src and your classes inside D:\Java classes. Then, use the following command to compile everything at once:

```
D:\Java\ >javac -cp classes -d classes src\pckg\*.java
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code has no problems, maybe there is a name-conflict with some other classes in your package.

Comment: there are only these two classes in my package folder pckg. First i compiled aa.java and the compilation was fine. Then i tried to compile bb.java but it gives an error message that cannot find symbol

Comment: the compiled aa.class file must be available in the same folder with bb.java when you try to compile bb.java.

Comment: aa.class is available in the same folder before compiling bb.java.

Answer (score 0):

Try

`javac -cp . *.java`

Assume that you are inside the 'pckg' directory.

@JB Nizet already answered I think.